# Magmi Skus imported KO: does not show which skus

Tags: magento, magmi

We are importing 500 products with Magmi in Magento. It are existing products that we are updating and we first made an export and now want to import the products with the same skus but get the notice Skus imported KO: 77.

Is there a way to see which skus are not imported. At the moment I have no idea which of the 500 products are updated and which are not, so I can also not find the problem?

Comment: You can enable email notification plugin and configure it.So every time you run a import process you will get an email with all this information.

Comment: If you wish you can also try with the below given link which has done job for us. But make sure when you are following this link please follow each and every steps properly otherwise it will create an issue for you. And if you are using this you won't require to use any other extension like email notification etc. Please find the link below.

http://technet.weblineindia.com/web/import-bulk-products-with-images-in-magento/

Comment: Hi Muk, thans for your reply, where can I find the email notification plugin? I have been searching in Google, and on Magmi.org, but can't find that one?

Comment: https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git/tree/master/magmi/plugins/base/general/emailreport

Comment: magmi/state/progress.txt contains the import log.
The UI running page is only a view of it. it should contain interesting info on lines with "skip" keyword.